# Form Sentences in Present tense from Words

Tags: nltk

I need to convert sentences from Future tense to present tense , I could not find some straight forward way to do that .

So is it possible to break a sentence into and then re frame the sentence in present tense ?

Before :- It has been determined that in Year 2018, 1 new procedure code is to be added to Dental Related Groups

After :- Determine if in year 2018 , 1 new procedure code is added to dental Related Groups